# AngularJS can't call MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new on angularJS, im trying to call my MVC jsonresult for get data and so populate a list but my GetLogs function won't go to the MVC jsonresult /misc/getlogs (i also tryed with full url). Code is:

```
<body ng-app="Log">
<div ng-controller="MiscController">
    <ul ng-repeat="log in logs" class="notification-body">
        <li>
            <span class="unread">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="msg">
                    <img src="/content/img/avatars/4.png" alt="" class="air air-top-left margin-top-5" width="40" height="40" />
                    <span class="from">John Doe <i class="icon-paperclip"></i></span>
                    <time>2 minutes ago</time>
                    <span class="subject">{{log.Name}}</span>
                    <span class="msg-body">Hello again and thanks for being a part of the newsletter. </span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetLogs();
    });

    function GetLogs() {
        var app = angular.module("Log", []);
        app.controller('MiscController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.post("/misc/getlogs")
            .success(function (data) { $scope.logs = data.logs; });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be call the getLogs() function on `document.ready` angular `ng-app` will run first and ask for the module and will throw and module error.

So the solution would be create a angular module when page gets loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("Log", []);
    app.controller('MiscController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.post("/misc/getlogs")
        .success(function (data) { $scope.logs = data.logs; });
    });
</script>
```

**Update**

If you want to load angular on the page lazily then do use `angular.bootstrap` that will initialize angular on the element silently. Before moving to this approach you need to remove `ng-app` directive from you page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetLogs();
    });

    function GetLogs() {
        var app = angular.module("Log", []);
        app.controller('MiscController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.post("/misc/getlogs")
            .success(function (data) { $scope.logs = data.logs; });
        });
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['Log'])
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks I used the function because I need to call it also from a button (for refresh). Anyway I can't reach my jsonresult (or actionresult) can't understand why

Comment: @Sauron I think if you are returning Json from your method that should have `JSONBehaviour.AllowGet` & should use `$http.get` instead of `post` ..

Comment: your "Update" work perfectly! Finally i can reach the jsonresult :) thanks man

Comment: @Sauron Glad to help you..would you mine to do upvote & accept answer..Thanks :)